# What do KerasRegressor object at 0x7f466c02fe20> & rv_frozen object at 0x7f46ed175580> thrown by sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.fit mean?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf.keras

I am trying to optimize the hyperparameters of a neural network in (Cent OS 8, Anaconda, Jupyter Notebook, Python) with the method sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.fit but the call to this method ended up outputing what seemed to me as an error. Do you know what the following output means and whether it is anything that needs to get fixed?

> RandomizedSearchCV(cv=3,
> estimator=<tensorflow.python.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor
> object at 0x7f466c02fe20>,
> param_distributions={'learning_rate': <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen object at
> 0x7f46ed175580>,
> 'n_hidden': [0, 1, 2, 3],
> 'n_neurons': array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
> 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
> 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51,
> 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68,
> 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85,
> 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])})

The whole code that gives the message displayed above looks like as follows:

```
## Data extraction  and standardization

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
# Getting the data
housing = fetch_california_housing()

#Splitting the data in training and testing data
X_train_full, X_test, y_train_full, y_test = train_test_split(
housing.data, housing.target)

# Splitting the training data in training data and validation data
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(
X_train_full, y_train_full)


# Standardizing the data: first substracting the mean value (so standardized
# values always have a zero mean), and then dividing by the standard deviation so that
# the resulting distribution has unit variance.
scaler = StandardScaler()

# Scale the training data with the mean and variance of the training data.
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
# Scale the validation data with the mean and variance of the training data.
X_valid_scaled = scaler.transform(X_valid)
# Scale the test dta with the mean and variance of the training data.
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

## Building a generic model for optimization of hyperparameters
def build_model(n_hidden=1, n_neurons=30, learning_rate=3e-3, input_shape=[8]):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    # inpute layer
    model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
    for layer in range(n_hidden):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_neurons, activation="relu"))
    #output layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
    
    # defining optimizer, learning rate and loss function of the model
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

## Creating a Keras regressor based on the previous model
from tensorflow import keras
# KerasRegressor is a wrapper of the model 
keras_reg = keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor(build_model)

## Defining randomized search for hyperparameters optimization
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import reciprocal
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
# Defining dictionary of hyperparameter distributions for randomized search
param_distribs = {
    "n_hidden": [0, 1, 2, 3],
    "n_neurons": np.arange(1, 100), #[1,2,......,98,99]
    "learning_rate": reciprocal(3e-4, 3e-2),
    }
# cv: The chosen number of cross validation folds determining how many times it will train each model on
#     a different subset of data in order to assess model quality.
# n_iter: amount of iterations. Each iteration represents a new model trained on a new draw from the dictionary
#         of hyperparameter distributions
# The total number of models random search trains is then equal to n_iter * cv
rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_reg,
                                   param_distribs,
                                   n_iter=10, cv=3)

## Training
# Training all the data of the scaled input training data set in each cycle out of the total 100 cycles.
# Too many epochs can lead to overfitting of the training dataset, whereas too few may result in an underfit model.
# Early stopping is a method that allows you to specify an arbitrary large number of training epochs and
# stop training once the model performance stops improving on a hold out validation dataset.
rnd_search_cv.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=100,
                  validation_data=(X_valid_scaled, y_valid),
                  callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])
```

I also gave it a try by running it on a Linux terminal instead of Jupyter Notebook as follows:

```
 python3 test.py > /dev/null 2>trace.txt
```

Then running

```
cat trace.txt
```

outputs the following on Linux terminal:

> 2021-11-08 00:03:30.792768: I
> tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA
> devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set 2021-11-08 00:03:30.797482:
> I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)
> to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical
> operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX512F FMA To enable them in
> other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler
> flags. 2021-11-08 00:03:30.804638: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new
> thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using
> inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance. 2021-11-08
> 00:03:30.848028: I
> tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of
> the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2) 2021-11-08
> 00:03:30.862445: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU
> Frequency: 1190400000 Hz

Thanks

Comment: `<Whatever object at 0x7f466c02fe20>` just means an instance of whatever class at some address in memory. And that doesn't actually look much like an error message? What's the traceback?

Comment: Well, I just realized that there does not seem to be any error's traceback. I only see the log of the training and after that it throws the output I mentioned in my question's post. So, may be you are right. Might I assume the hyperparameters search was carried out successfully then?

Comment: I think that may just be something printing an object. Are you *sure* it's an error?

Comment: No, I am not sure. I only saw what seemed to me like an strange message and I assumed that was an error. But I do not know how to get to know for sure whether that is an error or not. I only know the message is the output of the cell of JupyterNotebook that runs ```rnd_search_cv.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=100,
                  validation_data=(X_valid_scaled, y_valid),
                  callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])```

Comment: If you're on Mac or Linux you can do `python3 yourfile.py > /dev/null 1>&1` which will redirect STDOUT to nowhere and only print STDERR.

Comment: I am on Linux with anaconda and running this with Jupyter Notebook within an Anaconda environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238967/discussion-between-goahead97-and-jared-smith).